# MassTransit with Azure Service Bus topic subscription

Tags: masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have a consumer in MassTransit and it seems like it wants to listen for messages on a queue as default. It creates a topic with a subscription, and a queue. Messages are forwarded from the subscription to the queue.

How can I configure it to work directly with the subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to use a subscription, you will need to manually [configure the subscription](https://masstransit.io/documentation/transports/azure-service-bus#subscriptions).

```cs
cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<MessageType>("subscription-name", e =>
{
    e.ConfigureConsumer<MyConsumer>(context);
})
```

Comment: Great, thank! I didn't get from the documentation that configuring it like that would skip the queue.